# Updating column based on relation to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a `table_1` that looks something like this

```
NameId       SelectedName 
Null              A
Null              C
Null              F
```

`NameId` is a `FOREIGN KEY` that `REFERENCES table_2 (Id)`

And a `table_2` that looks like this

```
Id              Name 
1                A
2                B
3                C
4                D
5                E
6                F
```

I want to populate `NameId` with all of the `Id` numbers associated with the same `Name`, so for example, the final result would be:

```
NameId       SelectedName 
1                 A
3                 C
6                 F
```

So far, all I have is:

```
SELECT Id, `Name` FROM table_2 WHERE `Name` IN (SELECT `SelectedName` FROM table_1);
```

Which I then tried to follow up with:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET NameId = Id WHERE SelectedName = `Name`;
```

Which doesn't work. Not sure how to go about doing this or how to use previously selected columns and relations to get what I want done here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.SelectedName= table2.Name
SET table1.NameId = table2.ID
```

Comment: what you are showing is MSSQL sql syntax. It should be `UPDATE Table1 a
  INNER JOIN Table2 b
   ON a.SelectedName = b.Name
SET a.NameId = b.ID`

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to check tag.

Comment: Please spend a few moments and format your query +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1 a INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.SelectedName = b.Name SET a.NameId = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

First Update the `table_1.NameId` values with `table_2.Id`

```
UPDATE table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.SelectedName= table_2.Name 
SET table_1.NameId= table_2.Id
```

and retrieve the values from `table_1`

```
SELECT NameId, SelectedName 
FROM table_1 
WHERE SelectedName IN (SELECT Name FROM table_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This way will update relation table column when parent has update.**

```
DROP TRIGGER `table_2_au`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `table_2_au` AFTER UPDATE ON `table_2` FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE `table_1` T1
INNER JOIN `table_2` T2
ON T1.`SelectedName` = T2.`Name` 
SET T1.`NameId` = T2.`Id`;;
DELIMITER ;
```